# How to index a list by csv file names in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, path

I am running a data analysis where I am running many CSV files. 
I used the code below

```
filelist = ["C:\Users\jan.csv", "C:\Users\feb.csv", "C:\Users\mar.csv"]

for location in filelist:
   df = pd.read_csv(location)
   out_put, productivity = timeresult.input_data.outbuild(df, year, days)
   filelist.append(productivity)
```

Is there a way to have the index be the CSV name and not have the filename in the filelist anymore?

The filelist than created a list of my data analysis but I want the index name to be the csvfile name used in the filelist.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand this part

> Is there a way to have the index be the CSV name

For the last part, instead of doing `filelist.append(productivity)`, append it to an empty list like:

```
filelist=["C:\Users\jan.csv", "C:\Users\feb.csv", "C:\Users\mar.csv"]
filelist_new = []
for location in filelist:
    df = pd.read_csv(location)
    out_put, productivity= timeresult.input_data.outbuild(df, year, days)
    filelist_new.append(productivity)
```

Added for your followup question:
I don't know what `timeresult.input_data.outbuild` this does. But you can append a list like:

```
filelist=["C:\Users\jan.csv", "C:\Users\feb.csv", "C:\Users\mar.csv"]
filelist_new = []
for location in filelist:
    df = pd.read_csv(location)
    out_put, productivity= timeresult.input_data.outbuild(df, year, days)
    filelist_new.append([location.split('\')[-1], productivity])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My goal is to have the index name of the new filelist_new be csv file name which was used all the fileslist.

Comment: I get an "EOL while scanning string literal" after this ('\')[-1], productivity])   I tried to replace "\" with / to get rid of the error but it just  turned the whole filelist_new to just the csv name instead of just using the name of the file as the index.

Comment: If you want to use the full file name you can just omit `.split('\')[-1]`